# Discord.py how to check if the widget is disabled

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to check if the widget is enabled to avoid HTTP errors(404). But I can't find a way, even looking on the API reference. Can you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord rewrite does not have an option to check if a widget  is online. In order to check this is eventually checking if you can get a valid response. Thus in order to still be able to check you need to try something with the widget to check if it is online.

Whenever you get a HTTP error you know it is offline (or not able to operate).

What I suggest is create a simple function to check if it is online:

```
# Checks if the widget is online by 
# trying to access the widget through a guild object.
async def widget_is_online(guild):
    try:
        # or a function that needs online functionality
        await guild.widget()
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Something that is also a good idea. Is to use a try-except at the place you try to use the widget. Where the except catches an http error exception. This is probably better and faster than using a function described earlier, to prevent http errors.

Answer (score 0):

While I would generally advise against using except without a specific error, it ignores the exception when using urllibs HTTPError. If the Widget is disabled you should get a Forbidden: 403 Error though, not 404.

Since you haven't provided any code or example I've just written a small command that returns if the widget for the guild is available.

```
@bot.command()
async def check_widget(ctx):
    try:
        widget = await ctx.guild.widget()
        ctx.send("Widget Available!")
    except:
        await ctx.send("Widget unavailable!")
```